# How to do word-wrap based on a specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting a string from server side,which contains words separated by comma.
ex:- `09:30pm - 10.30pm,11.00pm - 12.00pm ...,...,....`
I want to display it like:

```
09:30pm - 10.30pm,
11.00pm - 12.00pm,
...,
...,
.
.
.
```

How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
serverResponse.split(",")
```

This will return an array of strings

Comment: This was not what was asked. It is only part of the answer. You need to split, and join to get to his requirements.

Comment: I've made a simple example here. Can you please take a look? https://jsfiddle.net/ntphdttz/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you're using the string, you could replace commas with either `\n` or `<br>`:

```
YourString.replace(/\,/g,",\n")
```

Comment: This won't work. Simply doing `.replace(',', '\n')` will replace the first occurence of a comma, but not all. You'll need to use a regular expression like so: `string2.replace(/\,/g, '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

Option 1:

```
var string1 = '09:30pm - 10.30pm,11.00pm - 12.00pm';
string1 = string1.split(',').join(',\n');
```

Option 2:

```
var string2 = '09:30pm - 10.30pm,11.00pm - 12.00pm';
string2 = string2.replace(/\,/g, ',\n');
```